# How to pass java Object from client to Webservice

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

Hello I am pretty new to web services I am trying to pass a java object to a web service I created where it has a Web method that takes a java object. I am attaching my code below.

The Web Service Class:

```
@WebService
public class WsTicketService {

    WsTicketStore ticketstore =  new WsTicketStore();

    @WebMethod
    public void createTicket(Ticket ticket) {
        System.out.println("Requested to store a new ticket");
        Ticket myTicket = ticketstore.storeNewTicket(ticket.getReporter(), ticket.getTopic(),ticket.getDescription(), ticket.getType(), ticket.getPriority());
        System.out.println("Ticket Stored");
    }
}
```

The client class which creates a ticket I want to send this ticket to the above webservice but I receive an error on line service.createTicket(Ticket) that the type is not applicable for the arguments.

```
public class WsTicketManagementBackend implements TicketManagementBackend {
    HashMap<Integer, Ticket> localTicketStore = new HashMap<>();
    AtomicInteger nextId;


    WsTicketServiceService client;
    WsTicketService service;

    public WsTicketManagementBackend() {
        nextId = new AtomicInteger(1);

        this.client = new WsTicketServiceService();
        service = client.getWsTicketServicePort();
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerShutdown() {

    }

    @Override
    public Ticket createNewTicket(String reporter, String topic, String description, Type type, Priority priority) {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(nextId.getAndIncrement(), reporter, topic, description, type, priority);
        localTicketStore.put(ticket.getId(), ticket);
        service.createTicket(ticket);
        return (Ticket) ticket.clone();
    }
```

This interface is generated by wsimport tool:

```
public interface WsTicketService {


    /**
     * 
     * @param arg0
     */
    @WebMethod
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "createTicket", targetNamespace = "http://implementation.remote.ws.backend.rz.uniba.de/", className = "de.uniba.rz.backend.ws.remote.implementation.CreateTicket")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "createTicketResponse", targetNamespace = "http://implementation.remote.ws.backend.rz.uniba.de/", className = "de.uniba.rz.backend.ws.remote.implementation.CreateTicketResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://implementation.remote.ws.backend.rz.uniba.de/WsTicketService/createTicketRequest", output = "http://implementation.remote.ws.backend.rz.uniba.de/WsTicketService/createTicketResponse")
    public void createTicket(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        Ticket arg0);

}
```

Comment: Hmm did you try passing an Object and then casting it to Ticket? that could be a workaround, or pass a Json with the attributtes to build the ticket object and build it inside your createTicket method, so it would receive a json string instead of the ticket object directly.

Comment: For the json part do I have change the type of ticket to String in createTicket in web service class?

Comment: Post the entire error.

Comment: yeah your method createTicket(Ticket ticket), would need to now receive String jsonTicket. so inside this createTicket(String jsonTicket) method you would set each property of your Ticket object to each attribute of your jsonTicket.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending a json String with the properties of your Ticket object and then create it, like so:

```
createTicket(String jsonTicket){
// Instantiate a jsonObject (you can use any json library you want, I recommend PrimeFaces JSONObject)
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonTicket);
// So here you make a new ticket
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
// Set the properties of the ticket to each attribute of your json
ticket.setName(json.getString("name"));
// and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using JAXB by Marshalling the java object to xml document on client-side and then unmarshalling on the web server-side back to java object.